# String Truncation in java

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string like

```
String email = "mailto://abc@gmail.com";
```

I want to get only the email address but without using a fixed number like

```
email.substring(9);
```

Any better approach.

Comment: dont't forget to add "" to your string :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String is of the [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) format so you could do

```
String email = "mailto://abc@gmail.com";
URI uri = URI.create(email);
String address = uri.getUserInfo() + "@" + uri.getHost();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression:

```
String email = "mailto://abc@gmail.com"; 
// Builds a pattern with a capturing group ()
Pattern mailtoPattern = Pattern.compile("mailto://(.*)");

// Give your string to a matcher generated by the compiled pattern
Matcher mailMatcher = mailtoPattern.matcher(email);

// If your String is correctly formatted you can attempt to capture 
// the content between parenthesis
if (mailMatcher.find()) {
    String mailValue = emailMatcher.group(1);
}
```

Using regular expressions will also help you validate the String given as input, you can even validate if the mail String is indeed a mail address (there are crazy people with all sorts of crazy expressions to validate them). I recommend you read the very thorough JavaDoc here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

Answer (score 0):

Not using regex

```
String string = "mailto://abc@gmail.com";
final String PREFIX = "mailto://";
String email = string.substring(PREFIX.length());
```